# Html.BeginForm POST overwrites image data when new image is not specified?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post, razor, html.beginform

This is my first post to StackOverflow.  I hope this is useful.

I have a Razor view that is intended to allow editing of the displayable properties of a model containing either pre-defined values or null values.  The view should not change the contents of the model's properties unless the user changes them intentionally by editing them on in the UI based on the view. The view behaves correctly, except with regard to a property of type `byte[]` that contains image data: `Model.ImageData`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ))
{

@Html.EditorForModel()

<div class="editor-label">Image</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @if (Model.ImageData == null)
    {
        @: No image has been assigned in the database.
    }
    else
    {
        <img width="150" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new { Model.ID} )" />
    }
    <div>Upload new image: <input type="file" name="Image" /></div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />

}
```

The above view works as intended for all properties in the model except `Model.ImageData`.  In this case, posting causes any previously set `Model.ImageData` to be set to null.  I have confirmed that the `Model.ImageData` is set to null during post by verifying that prior to posting, `Model.ImageData` contains a valid byte array (with the expected image).

The controller code for the above view is:

```
  public ViewResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
// breakpoint here shows that all model properties including product.ImageData are populated and valid.
        return View(product);
    }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase Image)  
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
// breakpoint here shows that product.ImageData is null (but all other model properties are still populated with data).
            if (Image != null)
            {
                product.ImageMimeType = Image.ContentType; 
                product.ImageData = new byte[Image.ContentLength]; 
                Image.InputStream.Read(product.ImageData, 0, Image.ContentLength); 
            }
            repository.SaveProduct(product);
            TempData["Message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", product.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(product);
        }
    }
```

And here is the respository code that updates the model (though the model is changing before this code is called):

```
public void SaveProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (product.ID == 0)
        {
            context.Products.Add(product);  // why doesn't this try to save ID = 0 to the ID field of the product in the database??
        }
        else
        {
            Product dbEntry = context.Products.Find(product.ID);
            if (dbEntry != null)
            {
                dbEntry.Name = product.Name;
                dbEntry.Description = product.Description;
                dbEntry.Category = product.Category;
                dbEntry.Price = product.Price;
                dbEntry.ImageData = product.ImageData;
                dbEntry.ImageMimeType = product.ImageMimeType;
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to include the minimal code in your controller data, that is setting/saving the model data. are you using `UpdateModel()`?

Comment: and add the `SaveProduct()` method as well then. Is it EntityFrameworks, Linq to Sql (dbml) ?

Comment: @arserbin3 The model is EF.  But please note the comments in both overloads of `edit()` in the controller code regarding the model properties - the `ImageData` property is set to null before the call to `repository.SaveProduct` (seems as though the model is modified by the framework somehow)...

Comment: No, the model is not 'modified by the framework'. The model is only the things that were auto-binded from `Edit(Product product, ...)`. So if you don't include the `model.Price` in your View for example, the auto-binding will have `Price=null` not `Price=whatever is in db`

Comment: @arserbin3: There is one observation that is inconsistent with your statement "the auto-binding will have Price=null not Price=whatever is in db":  The model `product` that is passed to the `View()` method contains data.  If the data is NOT EDITED before the `POST`, there is no new data to auto-bind.  However, most of the properties are not affected at all.  This is the issue -- all the properties such as `Price` and `Name` are not set to null by the auto-binder.  All properties in the model `product` are just as they were before the `View()` method executed, EXCEPT the `ImageData` property.

Comment: gone for the evening, but I think you have confusion about what the binding is actually doing. It does not fetch the product values from the database, so if you submit `/Edit?Product.ID=5&Product.Price=4.5`, the `product` variable in `[HttpPost]Edit(product, Image)` will have a null `product.Name` and `ImageData` etc.  If you save that exact object to the database it will overwrite the `Product` row where id=5 with a null Name. The `Product.ImageData` field is not being submitted with the `<form>` post, and is therefore null in `[HttpPost]Edit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really where you should consider using a `ViewModel` class instead. But to keep your current ways of doing things with minimal changes, try modifying the `SaveProduct()` method to the following:

```
public void SaveProduct(Product product, bool updateImage = false)
{
    context.Products.Attach(product);

    // mark product as modified
    var entry = context.Entry(product);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

    entry.Property(e => e.ImageData).IsModified = updateImage;
    entry.Property(e => e.ImageMimeType).IsModified = updateImage;   

    context.SaveChanges();  
}
```

and modify the controller code to:

```
...
var updateImage = false;
if (Image != null)
{
    updateImage = true;
    product.ImageMimeType = Image.ContentType; 
    product.ImageData = new byte[Image.ContentLength]; 
    Image.InputStream.Read(product.ImageData, 0, Image.ContentLength); 
}
repository.SaveProduct(product, updateImage);
....
```